# Can you tell me how to write a no-arg constructor for this class. The constructor should assign the sideLength field the value 0.0

Tags: constructor

```
public class Square {

    private double sideLength;

    public double GetArea() {

        return sideLength * sideLength;

    }

    public double GetSideLength() {

        return sideLength;

    }
```

}

Can you tell me how to write a no-arg constructor for this class. The constructor should assign
the sideLength field the value 0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think this is a very basic question, you must google it before asking here, though now you already asked, I try to answer it here as in the begging it's really tough to actually find the correct answer.

```
public Square (){
this.sideLength = 0.0;
}
```

As when you create a class java add a default constructor for you which is also no-args constructor, but you can always redefine and implement it.

You can refer this for more detail :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html